Microsoft Teams shared screen screenshots are blank on Azure Virtual PC
I am encountering this problem when using Teams from inside an Azure Virtual PC which I access through the Windows App, and I believe it is related to the problem described here - https://community.citrix.com/forums/topic/245394-microsoft-teams-screenshot-black/
Their solution is to disable this Optimization -

If Optimization is being used, this is expected behaviour.   With Optimization, when someone shares the desktop (or has their camera on) that section of the screen is processed on your endpoint  and then gets overlaid on top of your session by the Workspace app.   Consequently, when you take a screenshot within the session, it isn't able to see that part of the screen since it isn't really there - just being overlaid.

But they don't mention how to do this. How can I disable this overlay optimization that prevents screenshots from working?
My workaround right now is to run teams as a web client instead of the native app - screenshots work there.

I solved my issue a few weeks ago but forgot to add the solution. For me, uninstalling "Remote Desktop WebRTC redirector service" worked.
After this is uninstalled, you might need to Sign Out and then Sign In to the VPC or just reboot it, after which screenshots will work.

